# WPF label doesn't change its content

Tags: c#, wpf

I just started learning WPF  . I want to create simple clock that change label content for every new value .   I defined just one button in Grid

```
<Grid>
    <Label  FontSize="32"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="sec">
                Some Text 
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

This is code should change the value of the s and label text. When I Run program it doesn't start program it just load it for a long tme.

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     
     for (int s = 0; s<= 60; s++)
     {  
        sec.Content = s.ToString(); 
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
     
 }
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` blocks the UI thread. Use a `DispatcherTimer` or `await Task.Delay` in an async method.